# jQuery how to bind an element that is added via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the width of all elements in the list via jQuery but I am not sure how to bind it where it will read it from an AJAX loaded content.

Here is my code

```
// below html is loaded via AJAX
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>

var width;
$('ul li').each(function() {
width = (width + $(this).outerWidth());
});

console.log(width);
```

So from this code how can I modify it so that it will "bind/listen" to the elements that are loaded via AJAX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind events on elements that are dynamically loaded, you need to use the `.on()` method because event listeners are bound at the time of page load, and if your elements don't exist at that time, jQuery is unable to attach the event listeners.

So, in you care, if you wanted to attach a click event listener, you would bind the even ton an element that you are sure exists at the time of DOM ready (for eg. `body`).

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul > li', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

However, if you just want the width of the elements (as in your question), you do not need to bind using `.on()`. You just need to make sure that the elements exists when you check for their width. The best way to do this is run you code in the `success` callback of the AJAX request that loads in the content.

```
var width = 0;

$.get('example.php', function(data) {
   // this is the success callback

   // first add the new data to the document
   $('#someTarget').append(data);

   // you can now query for their width since they now exist
   $('ul li').each(function() {
      width += $(this).outerWidth();
   });

   console.log(width);
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This leads me to believe I actually asked the wrong question because My code some what works but it only works correctly in FF, webkit browsers and does not work in IE.  In IE, the width gathered is not correct and does not match what FF or webkit browser is seeing.  This is what let me to believe that I needed to "live" bind the element...But you explained that it doesn't need to and still able to get the width.  So now I am puzzled as to why it doesn't work the same in IE...Thanks again for replying.

Comment: You probably want to play around with [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/), [`innerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) and [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/). All browsers calculate width differently.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works on DOM elements. The methods are mostly run once the document is ready *(within so called $(document),ready() method)*. So the method which are initalized before the ajax call would not have access to the dynamically created elements. To achieve this you can initalize the bind method again within `complete` method of your ajax call. Following is an example:

### Example 1  : This would not work.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="get_ajax_data();">Get Data</button>
```

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    get_width();
    get_ajax_data();
});

function get_width(){
    # some code to get the width;
}

function get_ajax_data(){
    $.ajax({
        # Some code to get data from the ajax call
        # and then append it as a <li> to the <ul>
    });
}
```

In the above example, if you click on the button to get data, `get_width` method would not have access to the new `<li>` item that was added through ajax (dynamically) because at the point when `get_width` method was initialized that `<li>` element did not exist. So you need to do it as follows.

### Example 2  : This would work.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="get_ajax_data();">Get Data</button>
```

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    get_ajax_data();
});

function get_width(){
    # some code to get the width;
}

function get_ajax_data(){
    $.ajax({
        # Some code to get data from the ajax call
        # and then append it as a <li> to the <ul>
        complete: function(){
            get_width();
        }
    });
}
```

In the above what we did was to initialize the `get_width` method again after our ajax call was completed so that `get_width` also has access to the newly created elements.